# No change on the iTunes connect after "Submission Successful" on Xcode

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, submission

I submitted my new build from Xcode to the iTunes connect, it's shown "Submission successful". I pressed the button of Done.

And then, I went to the iTunes connect to check its state.
However, there is no mention about the new build, I assume the correct behaviour would be a sing of "Processing now" at the bottom of the page.

I have still waited for 1 hour, which is nothing to change.

Has anybody had the same issue before?

Cheers,

Comment: The same here, over 12 hours after successful upload. Apple sucks.

Comment: remember to read what tags say before using them. "processing" is not a generic term, it's the tag for questions about code involving the [Processing](http://processing.org) programming language.

Comment: I again submitted the same file from Xcode to iTunes connect. And then I got successful to upload. Please try to submit it again! Cc valter

Comment: So very sick of iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I again submitted the same file from Xcode to iTunes connect. And then I got successful to upload. Please try to submit it again! Cc valte